# java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: but file exists

Tags: java, android, xml

hi i've this little method:

```
private void modifyXML() {
        try {

            String filepath = main.fileWithPath;
            File f = new File(filepath);
            if(f.exists()){
                System.out.println("Exists");
            }



            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("DAQChannel");

//          int sorszam = table.row_id-1;
//
//          Node nNode = nList.item(sorszam);
//          
//          if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
//              Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
//              
//              eElement.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0).setTextContent(nameE.getText().toString());   
//              eElement.getElementsByTagName("Unit").item(0).setTextContent(nameE.getText().toString());
//              eElement.getElementsByTagName("Minimum").item(0).setTextContent(nameE.getText().toString());
//              eElement.getElementsByTagName("Maximum").item(0).setTextContent(nameE.getText().toString());
//              eElement.getElementsByTagName("Accuracy").item(0).setTextContent(nameE.getText().toString());
//              eElement.getElementsByTagName("SensorType").item(0).setTextContent(nameE.getText().toString());
//              eElement.getElementsByTagName("RegisterAddress").item(0).setTextContent(nameE.getText().toString());
//              eElement.getElementsByTagName("Offset").item(0).setTextContent(nameE.getText().toString());
//              eElement.getElementsByTagName("TimeStamp").item(0).setTextContent(nameE.getText().toString());
//          }

            // write the content into xml file
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

            String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

            String ujPath = filepath.substring(0, filepath.length()-10); 

            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(ujPath+"/config_midified_"+mydate+".xml"));
            transformer.transform(source, result);

            System.out.println("Done"); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException sae) {
            sae.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

it prints out that the file exists right in the begining, but than i got the error message
java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:

Please help me what did i wrong!

Thank you!

Comment: what is the value of `filepath`?!

Comment: Please include the full stack trace of your error.

Comment: 10-07 14:16:27.398: W/System.err(25753): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /storage/emulated/0/Ementor/config.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a `File` instance instead

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(filepath));
```

When passing a `String`, `DocumentBuilder#parse()` needs it to be in the `URI` format

```
[scheme:][//authority][path][?query][#fragment]
```

i.e. along with the protocol like `file://`.

*Reference :*
[DocumentBuilder#parse(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

The exception most likely means that you are providing a file pathname where a URL is required.  The message "Protocol not found" is used when the URL parser cannot find a protocol component in a URL; i.e. the characters before the first `:` in the URL.  If you are passing a pathname, there most likely isn't a `:` in the path.